# elasticsearch and logstash shutting down prematurely

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am pretty new to this and currently have a single unix (centos) server running logstash, elasticsearch and kibana. The data is being consumed from rabbitmq exchange and works pretty well but for some reason after a few hours the kibana dashboard will become inactive, the elasticsearch node inactive and logstash stops consuming. I initially set it up to manually start each process for eg. ./elasticsearch etc. and wonder if setting it up as a service would prevent this from occurring.

I want to ensure that the setup runs continuously without any interruptions.

```
http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/_plugin/head/
```

Any suggestions and links appreciated

Comment: If elasticsearch or logstash is crashing, you should check their own log files.  As you suggested, starting as a service is probably better (but whether it will help...).

Comment: thanks. I figured out why and it was related to memory consumption on the server